# list3 = list1 - list2 (netlogo)

Tags: list, netlogo

I am new to NetLogo, for patient-surgeon model, I need to create a `list3` which is `list1 - list2`. The `list1` and `list2` are comprised of the who number of the patients extracted from another list (for example, `SET list1 lput WHO list-n`).
I am using below code to subtract the list but I am not able to do so as model does not recognize `?` or `?1`. Please help me how to subtract two lists for n values.

```
set list1 []             
set list2 []
;; emptying the list to add the who number of patients
;; then setting the list as per the who number of agent

;; setup patients
SET list1 lput WHO list-n
SET list2 lput WHO list-k
```

What I want: `list3 = list1 - list2`

Query used:

```
to test-lists
  let list3 []

  foreach list2 [ 
    if (item (position ? list2) list1  = 1)[
      set list3 lput ? list3
    ]
  ]

end
```

But I get the error:

```
nothing named ? is defined
```

As per the manual, "? is always equivalent to ?1" and need not be defined. Kindly suggest how to go about with the subtraction of the list.

Comment: 1) `?` is old syntax, from before NetLogo 6.0. You need to use the arrow syntax, see the [transition guide](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/transition.html#v60). 2) ***Don't*** make lists of `who` numbers. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with them, but it's almost always a bad idea. Use lists of *agents* instead: store direct references to agents, not their `who` numbers.

Comment: Thanks nicolas...for your reply. I will read the guide and let you know. I'm using lput who because for identifying patients number which keeps changing on every setup click.i want to assign them surgery time and put them on various list. The only way to identify them and put them in the list was as per who number. But now I'll study list of agents and will try. Your answer really helped me to progress ahead.

Comment: Hi, Below is my new code. I am Healthcare research student trying to code for my research project, please consider that unlike other developers, I wont be able to relate the comments with other types of programming languages ( C, Java or Python), NetLogo being the first venture. I tried the new syntax but I am not able to relate the variables/ values used in the formula. I need your help in understanding what each value stands for code:         show (map [ [a b c] -> a + b = c ] [1 2 3] [2 4 6] [3 5 9]), her [ 1 2 3 ]

Comment: Here [ 1 2 3 ] are actual items of the list, how do I write this statement when my list1 lput who list1, and if I write this to get the actual values [ lput who list1 ] ;I get an error of expected literal value. I also tried giving it a variable but didn’t help. Please guide me further